# What is the difference between HTTP servlet and SOAP over HTTP?

Tags: java, http, servlets, soap

Asked in the interview:

- What is the difference between HTTP servlet and SOAP over HTTP?
- What the advantages and disadvantages of both?
- In which case would use which?

Comment: Interview questions are not real questions. This one is a false dichotomy, since most 'soap over http' services are deployed via a servlet.

Comment: @user401596, and what did you answer?

Comment: I guess you mean as a webservice mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention your background about the APIs mentioned.

In an interview they probably want to hear that a servlet processes a http-request and responses with a http-response as a soap does. The difference is that a soap request contains xml data (header and payload) which has to be parsed in a different way (usually with a framework like Xfire or Axis among others).

Answer (score 4):

I would ask if he / she could repeat the question, because it doesn't make much sense in my view. You could very well create a HTTP Servlet that returns SOAP via HTTP.

I guess you would have to explain first what [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is, and what a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) is.